# How to Include and exclude pages in wordpress when someone logs in?

Tags: wordpress

I have this so far

```
<?php 
    if(is_user_logged_in()) {
        wp_list_pages('sort_column=menu_order&depth=2&title_li=&exclude=104,101');
    }

    else {
        wp_list_pages('sort_column=menu_order&depth=2&title_li');
    }
?>
```

but how do I set it up so log out appears when someone is logged in?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using version 2.7 or later, what about this?

```
<? if (is_user_logged_in()): ?>
<a href="<?=wp_logout_url()?>">Log Out</a>
<? endif; ?>
```

or (if you want both log in and log out links):

```
<? if (is_user_logged_in()): ?>
<a href="<?=wp_logout_url()?>">Log Out</a>
<? else: ?>
<a href="<?=wp_login_url()?>">Log In</a>
<? endif; ?>
```

Note that you can give [wp_logout_url()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/wp_logout_url) and [wp_login_url()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_login_url) a single string argument containing a URL to which WordPress will redirect the visitor after login/logout.

#### Another Option

If you want the default WordPress login/out link without the ability to customize the HTML and are using at least version 1.5, try [wp_loginout()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_loginout):

```
<p><?=wp_loginout()?></p>
```

(Again, you can optionally provide a string URL redirect-to argument.)

Hope this helps,
Ben